# Difference between spring tx:advice and spring aop pointcut

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am new to spring, with working knowledge of hibernate.
My job was to implement transaction by using spring declarative approach.And successfully i did with the help of Google, thanks to Google. But not able to understand clearly about the terms I used in application-context.xml.

1.

```
 <tx-advice>

</tx-advice>
```

1. ```
   <aop-config>
       // here is point cut were declared
   </aop-config>
   ```

can somebody explain me about above point, Meanwhile I am trying to understand it from the google also.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

As you already successfully implemented `spring transaction`,

In `Spring` we can implement transaction in three ways:

1. **Platform Transaction Management.**
2. **[Declarative](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/transaction.html#transaction-declarative) Transaction Management.**
3. **[Programmatic](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/transaction.html#transaction-programmatic) Transaction Management.**

What you implemented is called **Declarative Transaction Management via XML**.

In short you did the implementation of `transaction` by Spring's [AOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) feature.

Coupling the `tx:advice XML` configuration with an XML based AOP configuration makes for synergistic combination. For example, we can use method names to automatically figure out what kind of transaction we want to apply on that method.

**Say** we want to apply the transaction on all that methods which start with `save` and `modify` such as `savePizza()`,`saveColdDrink()`,`modifyOrder()`,`modifyBill()`. For these we have to define the `advice` in our xml file:

```xml
<tx:advice id="txAdvice" >
  <tx:attributes>
    <tx:method name="save*" propagation="REQUIRED"/>
    <tx:method name="modify*" propagation="REQUIRED"/>
  </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>
```

Our advice is ready, as we said by using above line that we want transactions only on the methods which start with `save` or `modify`. Now we are going to say which beans require the above advice by using `pointcut` element of `aop-config`. For example let say we want to apply the transaction advice to all of the classes which are available inside the `com.mytransaction.service` package.

For this, we have to add the following line inside our xml file:

```xml
<aop:config>
  <aop:pointcut id="allServices"
    expression="execution(*com.mytransaction.service.*.*(..))"/>
  <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice" pointcut-ref="allServices"/>
</aop:config>
```

In-short, `<tx:advice>` mean what to do or which behavior of transaction we want to apply.
`pointcut` element inside `<aop-config>` says where we want to apply the transaction,
say `<aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice" pointcut-ref="allServices"/>`

Comment: How do I force close the transaction

Comment: @Betlista - What is the need of "tx:method". Why can't it be achieved via pointcut expr? Let's say in this example I can define pointcut to match all methods starting with "save" and "modify". Won't that suffice?

Comment: @user001, yes you can use expression too

Answer (score 2):

The `<tx:advice>` tag is specific for [Transaction Management](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/transaction.html) configuration whereas the `<aop:config>` tag can be used to do [Aspect-Oriented Programming](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/aop.html) in general.

[AOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) can be used for many more things than transactions, for example logging or access control. Also, transaction management does not necessarily have to be implemented using AOP, it's just the way it is usually done in Spring (but Spring also supports [Programmatic Transaction Management](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/transaction.html#transaction-programmatic)).