# How to retrieve Username from customRevisionEntity

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-envers

We are using Hibernate-envers 3.6.3.Final and I am getting tables are generated properly with @Audited annotations. I am using CustomRevisionEntity to store the user information and CustomRevisionListenner is stored the user information as well. But If I trying to retrieve the "username", It returns the following error.

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Hibernate Session bound to thread, and configuration does not allow creation of non-transactional one here
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SpringSessionContext.currentSession(SpringSessionContext.java:64) ~[spring-orm-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
```

My CustomRevisionEntity class,

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "revision_info")
@RevisionEntity(CustomEnversListener.class)
public class CustomRevisionEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @RevisionNumber
    private int id;

    @RevisionTimestamp
    private long timestamp;

    private String username;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public long getTimestamp() {
        return timestamp;
    }

    public void setTimestamp(long timestamp) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }

    @Column(name = "username")
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
```

CustomRevisionListener.java

```
public class CustomEnversListener implements RevisionListener {
    public void newRevision(Object revisionEntity) {
        CustomRevisionEntity customRevisionEntity = (CustomRevisionEntity) revisionEntity;
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
                .getAuthentication();
        customRevisionEntity.setUsername(authentication.getName());
    }
}
```

My table as follows,

```
mysql> select * from revision_info;
+----+---------------+-----------------+
| id | timestamp     | username        |
+----+---------------+-----------------+
|  1 | 1431693146030 | sky@test.com    |
|  2 | 1431693150805 | ram@test.com    |
|  3 | 1431693164895 | bobo@test.com   |
+----+---------------+-----------------+
3 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

I am able to retrieve the "rev" using the "timeStamp" and "timeStamp" using the "rev" using the following code,

```
AuditReader reader = AuditReaderFactory.get(session);
Date timestamp = reader.getRevisionDate(rev);
Number revision = reader.getRevisionNumberForDate(timestamp);
```

But I am unable to retrieve the entire row with custom field "username" values using the hibernate query.

```
Criteria criteria = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
                .createCriteria(CustomRevisionEntity.class)
                .add(Restrictions.eq("id", rev));
```

The above query returns the above error.. How do I solve this?? 
How to retrieve the values from the revision_info table?

The full stack trace of my error is,

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Hibernate Session bound to thread, and configuration does not allow creation of non-transactional one here
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SpringSessionContext.currentSession(SpringSessionContext.java:64) ~[spring-orm-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:687) ~[hibernate-core-3.6.3.Final.jar:3.6.3.Final]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) ~[spring-core-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:701) ~[spring-aop-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150) ~[spring-aop-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:91) ~[spring-aop-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172) ~[spring-aop-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:634) ~[spring-aop-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.6.0_31]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.6.0_31]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.6.0_31]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622) ~[na:1.6.0_31]
    at ognl.OgnlRuntime.invokeMethod(OgnlRuntime.java:870) ~[ognl-3.0.6.jar:na]
    at ognl.OgnlRuntime.callAppropriateMethod(OgnlRuntime.java:1293) ~[ognl-3.0.6.jar:na]
    at ognl.ObjectMethodAccessor.callMethod(ObjectMethodAccessor.java:68) ~[ognl-3.0.6.jar:na]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.accessor.XWorkMethodAccessor.callMethodWithDebugInfo(XWorkMethodAccessor.java:117) [xwork-core-2.3.20.jar:2.3.20]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.accessor.XWorkMethodAccessor.callMethod(XWorkMethodAccessor.java:108) [xwork-core-2.3.20.jar:2.3.20]
    at ognl.OgnlRuntime.callMethod(OgnlRuntime.java:1369) ~[ognl-3.0.6.jar:na]
    at ognl.ASTMethod.getValueBody(ASTMethod.java:90) ~[ognl-3.0.6.jar:na]
    at ognl.SimpleNode.evaluateGetValueBody(SimpleNode.java:212) ~[ognl-3.0.6.jar:na]
    at ognl.SimpleNode.getValue(SimpleNode.java:258) ~[ognl-3.0.6.jar:na]
    at ognl.Ognl.getValue(Ognl.java:494) ~[ognl-3.0.6.jar:na]
    at ognl.Ognl.getValue(Ognl.java:458) ~[ognl-3.0.6.jar:na]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlUtil$2.execute(OgnlUtil.java:309) ~[xwork-core-2.3.20.jar:2.3.20]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlUtil.compileAndExecute(OgnlUtil.java:340) ~[xwork-core-2.3.20.jar:2.3.20]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlUtil.getValue(OgnlUtil.java:307) ~[xwork-core-2.3.20.jar:2.3.20]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:423) ~[xwork-core-2.3.20.jar:2.3.20]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:287) ~[xwork-core-2.3.20.jar:2.3.20]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:250) ~[xwork-core-2.3.20.jar:2.3.20]
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.DeprecationInterceptor.intercept(DeprecationInterceptor.java:41) ~[struts2-core-2.3.20.jar:2.3.20]
```

My spring configuration is as follows,

```
    <bean id="transactionManager"
              class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
            <property name="sessionFactory" ref="xxxSessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <tx:advice id="customRevisionEntityAdvice" transaction-manager="transactionManager">
            <tx:attributes>
                <tx:method name="*" read-only="false" propagation="REQUIRED"/>
            </tx:attributes>
    </tx:advice>

    <aop:config>
        <aop:pointcut id="crePointcut"
                      expression="execution(* bla.bla.CustomRevisionEntity.*(..))"/>
        <aop:advisor advice-ref="customRevisionEntityAdvice" pointcut-ref="crePointcut"/>
    </aop:config>
```

my application-content.xml contains the following...

```
<bean id="auditEventListener" class="org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener" />

    <bean id="xxxSessionFactory"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>                  
                <value>bla.bla.domain.Myclass</value>
            </list>
        </property>

        <property name="eventListeners">
            <map>
                <entry key="post-insert" value-ref="auditEventListener"/>
                <entry key="post-update" value-ref="auditEventListener"/>
                <entry key="post-delete" value-ref="auditEventListener"/>
                <entry key="pre-collection-update" value-ref="auditEventListener"/>
                <entry key="pre-collection-remove" value-ref="auditEventListener"/>
                <entry key="post-collection-recreate" value-ref="auditEventListener"/>
            </map>
        </property>
```

Comment: Any inputs here really appreciated

Answer (score 6):

## Using Envers

You can query the `CustomRevisionEntity` using the `AuditReader`

```
AuditReader auditReader = AuditReaderFactory.get(entityManager);

//Here you find the revision number that you want
Number revisionNumber = getRevisionNumber(auditReader);

//then you use the auditReader :-)
CustomRevisionEntity cRevEntity = auditReader.findRevision(
                CustomRevisionEntity.class, revisionNumber );

//Then you can just get your Username
String userName = cRevEntity.getUsername();
```

Here is the method signature

```
 /**
 * A helper method; should be used only if a custom revision entity is used. See also {@link RevisionEntity}.
 * @param revisionEntityClass Class of the revision entity. Should be annotated with {@link RevisionEntity}.
 * @param revision Number of the revision for which to get the data.
 * @return Entity containing data for the given revision.
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException If revision is less or equal to 0 or if the class of the revision entity
 * is invalid.
 * @throws RevisionDoesNotExistException If the revision does not exist.
 * @throws IllegalStateException If the associated entity manager is closed.
 */
<T> T findRevision(Class<T> revisionEntityClass, Number revision) throws IllegalArgumentException,
        RevisionDoesNotExistException, IllegalStateException;
```

From the Hibernate-envers 3.6.3.Final source, this is implemented at AuditReaderImpl.java line 193:

```
@SuppressWarnings({"unchecked"})
public <T> T findRevision(Class<T> revisionEntityClass, Number revision) throws IllegalArgumentException,
        RevisionDoesNotExistException, IllegalStateException {
    checkNotNull(revision, "Entity revision");
    checkPositive(revision, "Entity revision");
    checkSession();

    Set<Number> revisions = new HashSet<Number>(1);
    revisions.add(revision);
    Query query = verCfg.getRevisionInfoQueryCreator().getRevisionsQuery(session, revisions);

    try {
        T revisionData = (T) query.uniqueResult();

        if (revisionData == null) {
            throw new RevisionDoesNotExistException(revision);
        }

        return revisionData;
    } catch (NonUniqueResultException e) {
        throw new AuditException(e);
    }
}
```

## Update - Missing Spring Configuration

Looking your stacktrace, you're missing some spring transaction configuration.
Either use a declarative configuration or use annotation.

#### Declarative Configuration

You need to declare the usage of transaction within the configuration xml, this is done using a AOP pointcut. Looking at this [example](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-declarative-first-example), you can see it first sets up the `TransactionManager` and it's `DataSource`, then declare that every method of `x.y.service.FooService` will require a transaction

```
<!-- ensure that the above transactional advice runs for any execution
     of an operation defined by the FooService interface -->
<aop:config>
    <aop:pointcut id="fooServiceOperation" expression="execution(* x.y.service.FooService.*(..))"/>
    <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice" pointcut-ref="fooServiceOperation"/>
</aop:config>
```

Your provided configuration is **missing** the AOP configuration. For convenience you can configure every class from a specific package to use transaction.

```
<aop:config>
    <aop:pointcut id="fooServiceMethods" expression="execution(* x.y.service.*.*(..))"/>
    <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice" pointcut-ref="fooServiceMethods"/>
</aop:config>
```

See that is just the `expression="execution(* x.y.service.*.*(..))"` that changes.

#### Using @Transactional

Spring thankfully provides a easier way to declare the usage of a `@Transactional` method, simply by annotating a Class, Interface or Method as `@Transactional`

```
// the service class that we want to make transactional
@Transactional
public class DefaultFooService implements FooService {

    Foo getFoo(String fooName);

    Foo getFoo(String fooName, String barName);

    void insertFoo(Foo foo);

    void updateFoo(Foo foo);
}
```

After that we need to configure spring to scan our code looking for @Transactional, to generate the proper proxy beans instances when needed.

```
<!-- enable the configuration of transactional behavior based on annotations -->
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager"/><!-- a PlatformTransactionManager is still required -->
```

Here is the [complete example](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-declarative-annotations) for @Transactional and my [reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html) for spring configuration about transactions.

## Envers Configuration On Hibernate 3

Hibernate 3 requires a special configuration to work with Envers, you need to add this at your `persistence.xml`. [Example](http://guidogarcia.net/blog/2012/01/25/auditing-jpa-entities-with-hibernate-envers/)

```
<property name="hibernate.ejb.event.post-insert" value="org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3PostInsertEventListener,org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener" />
<property name="hibernate.ejb.event.post-update" value="org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3PostUpdateEventListener,org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener" />
<property name="hibernate.ejb.event.post-delete" value="org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3PostDeleteEventListener,org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener" />
<property name="hibernate.ejb.event.pre-collection-update" value="org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener" />
<property name="hibernate.ejb.event.pre-collection-remove" value="org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener" />
<property name="hibernate.ejb.event.post-collection-recreate" value="org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener" />
```

In case you don't have a persistence.xml or hibernate.cfg.xml, and you declare the `SessionFactory` and it just works, you need to edit your spring configuration something like [this](http://j4fry.blogspot.com.br/2009/06/hibernate-event-listeners-with-spring.html)

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    ....
    <property name="eventListeners">
        <map>
            <entry key="post-insert" value-ref="auditListener"/>
            <entry key="post-update" value-ref="auditListener"/>
            <entry key="post-delete" value-ref="auditListener"/>
            <entry key="pre-collection-update" value-ref="auditListener"/>
            <entry key="pre-collection-remove" value-ref="auditListener"/>
            <entry key="post-collection-recreate" value-ref="auditListener"/>
        </map>
    </property>
    ...
</bean>

<bean id="auditListener" class="org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Andre! Still am getting the same error... "org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Hibernate Session bound to thread, and configuration does not allow creation of non-transactional one here
"

Comment: Well, then this is more likely a issue with the spring configuration. Can you post the full stacktrace?

Comment: I have added the full stacktrace at the end of my question... kindly take a look at it and provide your thoughts...

Comment: Added some clarification about Spring configuration. @SST

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply @Andre!!! now am getting the following error.. org.hibernate.envers.exception.AuditException: You need to install the org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener class as post insert, update and delete event listener.

Comment: I have edited and included envers configuration in my application-context.xml

Comment: What is your Spring version? Also, why `<property name="sessionFactory" ref="xxxSessionFactory"/>` on your TransactionManager and why `<bean id="sessionFactory" />` There are two different SessionManagers? @SST

Comment: My Spring version is "3.1.0.RELEASE" Sorry that ref is typo error.. but my file is having the correct structure

Comment: There isn't much to add for now. Debug your `org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean` to see if is reading the proper event listeners. And debug `public static AuditReader get(Session session) throws AuditException`

Answer (score 2):

That error is most often caused by the presence of a `TransactionManager` and trying to execute a query-method that's not marked as @Transactional, or possibly a too-broad `<tx:advice ...` bean definition. Can you show ud the revelant parts of your spring config?

TL;DR: Try adding `@Transactional` to the method querying `CustomRevisionEntity` and see if that helps. If yes, get to work with transaction demarcation.

**Update**: Your spring config requires transactions on all methods. You might add a

```
<tx:method name="read*" read-only="true"/>
```

to match your audit read-methods (change `read*` to something sensible, and make sure the `"*"` doesn¨'t catch-all). You can even add the attribute `propagation="SUPPORTS"` to this tag, to enable making use of an existing transaction, if you're querying in such a context.

Also, surely you have a `TransactionInterceptor`/auto-proxy somewhere?

```
<bean id="txInterceptor" class="org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor">
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager"></property>
    <property name="transactionAttributeSource" ref="txAttributeSource"/>
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.BeanNameAutoProxyCreator">
    <property name="beanNames">
        <list>          
            <value>yourServiceName<value>
            ...
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="interceptorNames">
        <list>
            <idref local="txInterceptor"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Cheers,

Comment: Hi Anders, I have already added the @Transactional in my querying class on the method and also configured <tx:advice ... in my application-context.xml but it didn't work...

Comment: I have posted my spring config at the end of my question.. Kindly look at it and provide your suggestions

Answer (score 2):

You are missing pointcuts definitions, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12873570/difference-between-spring-txadvice-and-spring-aop-pointcut).

Pointcuts help you define where you want your advice to be applied.

Comment: No Dragan.. I did the config also..  still am getting the same error.. :( kindly see my last edit in my question.

Comment: Ok, obviously there is more than this that causes the issue, but it was a missing part anyway.